# Efficient way of scrolling to part of page with jQuery links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've asked for help in regards to a scroll identifier and now have this code working perfectly:

http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/Kgcoa

However, I was wondering how I can get it so when I click the links on the black scrollbar I can get it to scroll to that part of the page. I think it would be something along these lines:

```
$(".a1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#a1").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

The scroll identification bit of the JavaScript has been so refined that I was really hoping there would be an elegant and optimised way to make it so they can skip to bits of the page too.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution imho, as long as you include the class / id portions in your nav / sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("nav span").click(function() {
    var sectionId = $(this).attr('class')
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+sectionId).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LPnp/2/)

Comment: That works, thank you. Can you show me how I can integrate this into the existing code?